# How do I get my code to re-enter the loop after an invalid input

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement

The code does what I want it to but I wanted to take it a little further. At the moment if the user enters a wrong name, it'll output "Author not found" then end.

How can I make it re-enter the code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] author = {"William Shakespear", "Mark Twain", "Jane Austin", "Charlotte Bronte", "Louisa May Alcott",
            "Lewis Carroll", "D.H. Lawrence", "Charles Dickens", "Lucy Maud Montgomery", "Alexander Dumas" };
        Console.WriteLine("Please type in an Author: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        int location = linearUnsorted(author, name);
            if (location == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Author not found, please try another");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is located at {1} in the poll", name, location + 1);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static int linearUnsorted(string[] arr, string item)
    {
        int location = 0;
        while (location <arr.Length && !String.Equals(item, arr[location], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            location++;
        }
        if (location == arr.Length)
        {
            location = -1;
        }
        return location;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your logic in the loop and continue until input is invalid:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] author = {"William Shakespear", "Mark Twain", "Jane Austin", "Charlotte Bronte", "Louisa May Alcott",
    "Lewis Carroll", "D.H. Lawrence", "Charles Dickens", "Lucy Maud Montgomery", "Alexander Dumas" };

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please type in an Author: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        int location = linearUnsorted(author, name);
        if (location == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Author not found, please try another");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is located at {1} in the poll", name, location + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Been racking my brains over this for hours haha. Still new at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with while loop.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type in an Author: ");
int location;

while(location = linearUnsorted(author, Console.Readline()) == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Author not found, please try another: ");
}

Console.WriteLine("{0} is located at {1} in the poll", name, location + 1);
```

P.S You should probably use `int index = Array.IndexOf(author, name);` to take the index of item in array or `Array.FindIndex(author, t => t.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))` if you want to case insensitive check.

Comment: What is the `name` parameter in this code for?  It doesn't seem to be populated.  Perhaps you meant `while(location =  linearUnsorted(author, Console.ReadLine()) == -1)`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I don't see how he define his linearUnsorted. it should be author, Console.Readline(). Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the mistake in my comment and corrected it.  Thanks.